# access raspberry via computer or external monitor

Tags: remote, vnc, screen, desktop

I want to programm a selfdriving car with visual recognision therefor I will later use opencv4.

When connecting the Pi via computer I have a problem concerning the remote desktop connection and vnc viewer. I get the following errors:

1. Remote access to the server is not enabled
2. The remote computer is turned off
3. The remote computer is unavailable on the network
4. or sometimes "connection timed out"

Therefore I was wondering whether I can just connect the Raspberry to an external monitor, keyboard and mouse without ever connecting the Pi to my computer. So does the Pi need to communicate later onwards with a device with a large computing capacity in order to recognize the pictures from opencv or is coding it via monitor enough?

Comment: You'll need to enable VNC or ssh on the pi before being able to use those options. You'll want to able to connect to it in order to program it, right? You should be able to find instructions online on how to enable those options.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi is a self contained computer.  It does not need to be connected to any other computer.